# Flex - User uploaded audio swfs makes the parent application to run at higher frame rate

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash

I had been developing one Flex application , in that users are allowed to upload there own swfs . The problem is, my application has a frame Rate of 11 , if the user tries to upload the swf  with higher frame and audio with it( ie Framerate of 24 with AudioFLV ). this makes  my application to run at the higher frame rate of that same user uploaded swf.

Can anyone pls help on this strange issue . i dont know how to overcome it.

Comment: Why does your app need to run at 11 FPS? What are your limitations?

Answer (score 0):

1. There can be only 1 framerate in your app.
2. The loaded swf can access the stage and change the framerate.
     So basically you cannot have access or restrict the swf loaded by your users not to change the fps.
3. You could always manually set the app fps to 11 each time the loaded swf ends.

This is not a solutions, but more a workaround.

Comment: Adrian Pirvulescu Thanks for your reply . I agree with what u said . The only problem i have is , if the user tries to upload the SWF which contains some audio in it. Application is performing at higher frame rate. Even if i trace the Application frame rate it still remains 11  . How to control my application, if the user uploads audio swfs . For other things it is working fine. no issues in it.

Comment: If the trace is showing all time 11 fps, are you sure that fps is changing or this is just some side effect. Can you post a live sample ?

Comment: Adrian Pirvulescu sorry for the late reply. i fixed that issue by manually playing the swfs of my application like( mc.nextFrame() ).And i have one problem if i have a Flv video inside my swfs , and if i play like next frame , the audio is not playing with the frame . this happens only if the swfs has some flv video inside it. Is there any way to detect whether FLV is inside the useruploaded swf.

Comment: Not so good into checking what's inside a swf. Anyway this may be a security issue and you may not be allowed to do it (but not sure). I really do not know what to say about this :( but glad you found the mx.nextFrame() solution/workaround :)